# How do I troubleshoot hung phusion passenger process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, hung

Every night when we run our batch jobs, passenger becomes unresponsive to http requests from customers. After a period of time it starts working again.

There are no errors in the rails log, actually I dont see any logging at all during the hung time.

In the Apache access log we see all the requests returning 500 errors:

```
ipaddress removed - - [09/Nov/2010:00:30:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 878 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"
```

In the apache error log we see:

```
 [ pid=31562 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:656 time=2010-11-08 15:23:49.68 ]:
   Either the vistor clicked on the 'Stop' button in the web browser, or the visitor's connection has stalled and couldn't receive the data that Apache is sending to it. As a result, you will probably see a 'Broken Pipe' error in this log file. Please ignore it, this is normal. You might also want to increase Apache's TimeOut configuration option if you experience this problem often.
```

I ran some passenger utils, here is the output

passenger-memory-stats

--------- Apache processes ---------

### PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name

950   2012  312.1 MB  28.2 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
993   2012  309.4 MB  27.6 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1014  2012  310.8 MB  26.8 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1038  2012  310.8 MB  26.9 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1050  2012  309.4 MB  27.6 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1055  2012  302.1 MB  20.1 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1057  2012  310.9 MB  26.9 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1059  2012  308.4 MB  26.5 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1060  2012  310.9 MB  27.1 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1109  2012  315.5 MB  33.4 MB  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2012  1     284.0 MB  1.7 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

#### Processes: 11

#### Total private dirty RSS: 272.87 MB

-------- Nginx processes --------

#### Processes: 0

#### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB

----- Passenger processes -----

### PID    VMSize    Private  Name

1052   249.3 MB  78.6 MB  Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /u/apps/demandmart/current
1108   254.8 MB  82.1 MB  Rails: /u/apps/demandmart/current
31088  87.1 MB   0.5 MB   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/ext/apache2/ApplicationPoolServerExecutable 0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/bin/passenger-spawn-server  /usr/bin/ruby1.8  /tmp/passenger.2012
31089  47.5 MB   9.8 MB   Passenger spawn server

#### Processes: 4

#### Total private dirty RSS: 171.06 MB

passenger-status

----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 1
active   = 0
inactive = 1
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Domains -----------
/u/apps/demandmart/current: 
  PID: 1108    Sessions: 0    Processed: 4       Uptime: 18m 8s

Any ideas, what can I try/do to figure this out. I tried killing with SIGABRT, ut the log says I dont have gdb installed. So I can install that and try again tomorrow, but im curious if this is normal or what else I should try?

Using apache2, phusion 2.2.11, ruby 1.8, rails 2, ubuntu

Comment: try passenger 3?  It is supposed to fix the hang issue..  I would have this happen on FreeBSD, and restarting apache would "fix" it for a bit..

Answer (score 0):

Your Phusion Passenger processes don't look hung to me, all the status information indicate that Phusion Passenger is idle. Maybe it's a problem in Apache.

Comment: well apache works fine, all static content is served up. The user gets the were sorry something went wrong only when trying to get to the rails application.